# How to locate a index in a column value

Tags: java, sql, oracle

How to locate a index in a column value

For example:

Database : Oracle

```
INSTR('-',AEND_NATIVE_EMS_NAME)
```

I need to find the index of first occurrence of `-` in column `AEND_NATIVE_EMS_NAME`

For MySql DB I was using

```
LOCATE('-', l.AEND_NATIVE_EMS_NAME)
```

which is working fine for me.

Please help me out with oracle

Comment: why not do it in java?

Comment: Switch parameters in the `INSTR` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the parameters inversely

```
INSTR(AEND_NATIVE_EMS_NAME, '-')
```